# How best to loop over a gulp task without iterating until each loop is complete

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

Can anyone suggest the best way to build multiple css files from multiple sass files?

Using NodeJs I'm looping through a directory. Files in that directory each have different sass variables. I need to loop through all the files and build their equivalent css.

A simplified example:

```
fs.readdir('folderPath', function(err, files){
   _.forEach(files, function(file){
       return gulp
           .src(file)
           .pipe(sass())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('somewhere'))
   })
})
```

This works but I'm processing 100s of large sass files (with many @imports) and because it's done synchronously it's incredibly slow. My pretty powerful machine crawls. It's a guess but would doing it asynchronously mean gulp isn't processing 100 streams at a time, rather one after the other?

If it requires some sort of promise how would I go about doing that?  Or some other nice solution or suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the equivalent:

```
gulp.task('something', function() {
   return gulp.src('folderPath/*')
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(gulp.dest('somewhere'))
});
```

If you want to target only sass files use `folderPath/*.scss` as glob.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options

Comment: That's a really good suggestion.  My simplified example is a cover for a more complex requirement and that complexity meant I forgot how simple it could be!  I'll see if this method can be applied to my requirements and report back :).   thanks

Comment: Yep. Perfect inspiration.  Cheers

Comment: Is there any way we can pipe the files into our own methods? (I just want the file names and to be able to do my own nefarious tasks with them without having to implement a whole stream class.)